# Change vote breakdown on user profiles

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Please can we change the way we display the vote break-down on user profiles. At present we have a breakdown giving four vote total figures like this:

[image]

I propose this be changed to a [contingency table/cross tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) like this:
[image]

This would mean we are not *displaying* any more information or using more space, but it is trivial to derive the first table from the second (row and column sums), but not vice-versa.

---

<sup>For this with a passing interest, the vote totals here are the SO site-wide all-time totals as of posting this question (if my handle of the SE data explorer is correct, but that is *far* from certain).</sup>

Comment: Not sure why is this so important to you, but I sure feel relief that I'm not the only one who have no idea how to read this strange table.

Comment: Ah, now I'm confused... Wouldn't the second representation reveal more information than the first one?

Comment: @DavidArenburg well I was browsing some well-known profiles (within certain tags), some with many down votes, and I was wondering if they were more predisposed to downvoting questions or answers and I realised that this information was not calculable from what was displayed. Then I wondered *why not*?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi exactly. That is my point! The sum of the first column of the second table gives the total up votes from the first. You cannot however go back given the information in the first table :-)

Comment: My guess would be questions, otherwise they woldn't have so much rep, wouldn't they ;)

Comment: @Simon, revealing more information about votes is always a tricky subject. This has to be carefully weighed for impacts before being implemented, if ever.

Comment: This has also always bothered me as well (from a data aesthetics perspective). I also don't happen to think that revealing up/down vote totals by question and answer separately is particularly concerning.

Comment: Related from MSE on the opposite side of the issue: [Why is vote count exposed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198234/why-is-vote-count-exposed)

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Not necessarily, downvoting an answer costs 1 rep, getting an upvote on answer gets 10 rep, so for each upvote on an answer you receive, as long as you cast less than 10 downvotes on answers, you are still better off. Believe me, rep grows so quickly I would be hard-pressed downvoting enough to reverse the curve.

Comment: @MatthieuM., Sorry I forgot to add the [tag:Joke] tag

Comment: Might as well add "total" for both columns and rows...

Comment: @AndrewT. I thought this too, but didn't want to change the quantity of information on display. I thought a like for like substitution would be the most likely scenario to possibly be accepted.

Comment: What about digit grouping? Numbers larger than 6 or 7 digits requires mental grouping to determine the magnitude of the most significant digit, which is all I (and I imagine others) really care about with numbers that large.

Comment: @kurtzbot remember the example above is for the whole site. The figures on an individual's profile page will be much lower. Even the [**all-time leading voter**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/998692/user998692) on SO has only 33k votes (none of which are down votes - what a nice user!) so this is less of an issue, but could still be handy.

Comment: Your suggestion *is* using more space, because you would need another row for the Upvotes/Downvotes header.

Comment: Why don't we make a step further and add a total count as well? Is an extra line in profile that important?

Comment: @AndriyM no, same space, just a different shape. The up votes/downvotes labels are currently in an additional column.

Comment: @tonytonov I personally *would* also like to see this. I don't know if other might think it information overload. I don't think it's a big deal and I think it would be an improvement too.

Comment: Well, I was talking about vertical space, but I forgot there was already a header row in the Votes section. If upvotes/downvotes are meant to be on the same row as currently "all time" and "by type" are then it would indeed seem to be no change in terms of space.

Comment: Perhaps a mod or community manager could weigh in and let us know if it would or is being considered?

Answer (score 21):

If this is to be implemented, I propose that we can **view the total sum** of the column / row by hovering over the description label.

[image: img]

Comment: @kurtzbot Currently, [the profile vote count summary has grouping with a comma every three digits](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a9a3k.png). I think that would happen to the new vote breakdown display and the hover sum count as well.